# How to create a sublist of dropdown menu with react-dropdown-select?

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I wish to create a sublist of a dropdown menu when I click on "Specific" option. I am very new here and I only know how to make a basic dropdown with react-dropdown-select. Also, I do not understand why there is so many options such as dropdown, dropdown-menu and etc. So I went and choose dropdown-select in the end but I can't search any examples of creating a sub dropdown with this method.

I also wish to create a sub dropdown for the "Specific" option with the design as shown in the screenshot below but again, I have no clue how.

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from "react-dropdown-select";

const timeOption = [
{
  label: 'Last Hour',
  value: 'Last Hour'
},
{
  label: 'Last Day',
  value: 'Last Day'
},
{
  label: 'Specific',
  value: 'Specific',
  submenu: [{
    label: "Day to Day",
    value: "Day to Day"
   }]}
]


  function Analysis() {

    return (
      <div className="box">
        <div className="selectionbar"> 
          <div className ="dropdown">
            Time Selection
            <Select 
                className="timeselection"
                options={timeOption} 
                placeholder={timeOption[0].label}  // By default should be "Last Hour"
            />
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>

  )
}



export default Analysis
```

[image]